# How to export or preview page content `onClick` as pdf/xls in the browser in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best practice to export or preview page content `onClick` as pdf/xls in the browser?

From my inexperienced understanding, I have to create an action/function that generates a static page content to pdf. Please correct me if I'm wrong and help me with implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is not the File-> Print page function, if you are talking about actually generating a file, there are a couple of libraries out there to do that. That problem is not specific to React.

A good JavaScript library to generate pdfs is [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake). I have used it in a project, although I used it in a backend Nodejs server. It may also work in the frontend directly. I suggest you try leaving the pdf generation to the backend though, then you need only download the file after making a request with some data from the frontend.

Comment: Thanks! will have a look to it. It seems `pdfmake` takes the data and converts to pdf with given styles. Just wondering whether/how it's possible to implement semantic-ui react components for styling?

Comment: @karolis2017 I also use semantic-ui-react, but I don't think you can use any React component to make the pdf. You have to write it from scratch. They allow you to have styles similar to css. There seems to be an open issue about converting actual html to pdf: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/205